# How to pass custom filter function to Where-Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

For last hours I'm trying to figure out how to pass a scriptblock to a function to be used as a filter for where object. I haven't found any documentation, I must be missing something. I saw "filter script:" and "function:script" definitions in [What is the recommended coding style for PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025989/what-is-the-recommended-coding-style-for-powershell) but I have no idea how these are used and I can't find it anywhere.

```
function Test
{
    Param(
            $f,     
            $What
    )

    $x = $What | where $f
    $x
}

$mywhat = @('aaa', 'b', 'abb', 'bac') 
filter script:myfilter {$_ -like 'a*'}
Test -What $mywhat -xx $myfilter
```

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what you're asking for here.

A filter is a function and not a scriptblock. `where-object` takes a scriptblock as an input. If you want to specify the where condition inside a function using a parameter, you could use a scriptblock-parameter.

```
function Test
{
    Param(
            [scriptblock]$f,     
            $What
    )

    $x = $What | where $f
    $x
}

$myfilter = {$_ -like 'a*'}
Test -What $mywhat -f $myfilter

#or combine them
Test -What $mywhat -f {$_ -like 'a*'}
```

If you simply wanted to use a filter, then this is how to do it:

```
filter script:myfilter { if($_ -like 'a*') { $_ }}

$mywhat | myfilter
```

That will be the equal to `$mywhat | where {$_ -like 'a*'}`

Comment: Thanks Graimer! That's what I was looking for and I believe I have tried this in the very beginning - had to still have something wrong.