# Random time selection logic is not working and loops forever

Tags: powershell, random, cycle

My input is a text file with license plate and date for tire repair. I am then  prompted to write a time e.g like 12:30. Then the script checks if the time is good or not. It's good if there is 30 minutes after and before not being used.

Using the example won't work since the 12:00-13:00 block contains an entry. Then the time isn't good, so the script has to search a good date for me. I tried to check line by line minute per minute. After, if the `$help` variable didn't change then it's good, but if it did, then make a random time, to check. Any ideas why that logic is not working?

**Edit:** Since I edited, the only thing I saw that isn't working, is that my script generates a random time, but it didn't check if that time is right, just accept that time and goodbye. Somehow I should make it to check it more times, and don't stop at the first generated time, check it, and if its still wrong, then randomize it again.

Sample data

```
ABC-145    8:30
BDE-540 9:45
EDS-598 10:30
SDF-478 11:30
HUT-434 12:15
JEC-238 13:15
ASD-325 14:00
VRA-123 16:15
HGV-456 18:00
```

```
$file = Get-Content Desktop/database.txt
[datetime]$time = Read-Host "Time for date?"
$start = $time
$check = $time
$help = 0
echo $time
foreach ($line in $file) {
    #here I check if the date is free
    $out = $line.Split()
    while ($true) {
        #until I found a good time
        for ($i=0; $i -lt 30; $i++) {
            #check the next half hour if good
            if ($time -eq $out[1]) {
                $help = 1
            }
            $time = $time.AddMinutes(1)
        }
        for ($i=0; $i -lt 60; $i++) {
            #back check the half hour
            if ($time -eq $out[1]) {
                $help = 1
            }
            $time = $time.AddMinutes(-1)
        }
            $time = $time.AddMinutes(30)
        if ($help -eq 0) {
            break
        } else {
            $hour = Get-Random -Minimum 8 -Maximum 20
            $minute = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 59
            $start = "$ora`:$perc" 
            $time = $start
            $help = 0
            #echo $time
        }
    }
}
if ($start-ne $check) {
    echo "There wasnt a free date, but there is a free spot at " + $start
} else {
    echo "This is free date"
}
```

Comment: I tried to fix the wording a little. Also [you really need to use some indentation coding style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025989/what-is-the-recommended-coding-style-for-powershell). It makes the code easier to read and you can see how nested statements flow much easier. This is a bonus for you _and_ people that want to help you.

Comment: Thank you, yes, i just did at the moment too in my local script, but still dont know what is the problem :/ If i write a obvious bad time like 12:15, then its got that, thats a bad value, but then it keep making random times and if i break it, then it stops at the 6th, not at the first, so i am so confused  :)

Comment: I think I've got the solution in mind. So the problem is after it randomed a time, it's keep moving in the while cycle from the last record, and somehow i should go back to the while/foreach cycle's beginning.

Comment: `$_` is an [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables). Don't (ab)use it as the loop variable of a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Edited as $line but still the same. I don't know why but i still get 16:04 as answer but there is a date at 16:15.

Comment: First you should take a step back and explain a) what you consider a "good time", and b) what your time grid is (seems to be quarter hours). Then update your question with that information as well as your modified code.

Comment: A good time is when there is no date before and after 30 minutes in database. So 14:40 is a good date, cause 14:00 is 40 minutes before and 16:15 is 1 hour 35 mins after

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a different approach. First extract the times from your input file and convert them to `DateTime` values:

```
$times = Get-Content 'Desktop/database.txt' |
         ForEach-Object { $_.Split("`t")[1] | Get-Date }
```

From that list determine the intervals that are actually wide enough to fit another appointment (at least 30 min after the previous and before the next appointment respectively, hence a minimum time window of 60 minutes):

```
$available = 0..($times.Count-1) |
             Where-Object { ($times[$_+1]-$times[$_]).TotalMinutes -ge 60 }
```

Pick a random index from that list and add 30 minutes to the corresponding time:

```
$index = $available[(Get-Random -Maximum $available.Count)]
$start = $times[$index].AddMinutes(30)
'{0:HH:mm}' -f $start
```

Or, if you want some more variation, calculate a new starting time from the timeframe 30 minutes after the previous appointment to 30 minutes before the next appointment like this:

```
$index  = $available[(Get-Random -Maxmimum $available.Count)]
$delta  = ($times[$index+1]-$times[$index]).TotalMinutes - 60
$offset = 30 + [int](Get-Random -Maximum ($delta + 1))

$start = $times[$index].AddMinutes($offset)
'{0:HH:mm}' -f $start
```

This approach ensures that you don't run into an infinite loop when there are no available timeslots left.